# Display a for loop in my return findSingleOrNoItem() in java

Tags: java

How can I add in my return `findSingleOrNoItem()` at the end of the statement to display the for loop counter `getClassName()` and `getAbsolutePercentage()` in the `findSingleOrNoItem()` statement? The reason I added a counter, some will have 4 values of `getClassName()` and `getAbsolutePercentage()` and some will have 6 values? so this will depend on the cosModel that gets passed on setParameter 1.

```
@Override
public TrafficProfile getTrafficProfileByCosClassAllocationNew(CosModel cosModel, Direction direction, 
        List<ClassOfServiceAllocation> cosClassAllocation, RouterType routerType) throws Exception {


    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    logger.info("Starting getTrafficProfileByCosClass2Allocations cos2 " );
    Query query = em.createNativeQuery(buildTrafficProfileByCosClassAllocationQueryNew(cosModel, direction,  cosClassAllocation, routerType), TrafficProfile.class);
    query.setParameter(1, cosModel.name());
    query.setParameter(2, direction.name());
    int i= 2;
            for(ClassOfServiceAllocation alloc : cosClassAllocation){
                query.setParameter(i++, alloc.getClassName());
                query.setParameter(i++, alloc.getAbsolutePercentage());
            }

    return findSingleOrNoItem(query, "Traffic_Profile", "cos_model = " + cosModel.name() + ", direction = " + direction.name() +  ?;
}
```

I am following this existing code below but this is only for cos6. I will have both cos4 and cos6 so I can't hard coded.

```
@Override
public TrafficProfile getTrafficProfileByCosClassAllocations(Direction direction,
        ClassOfService6Allocations cosClassAllocation, RouterType routerType) throws Exception {

    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    logger.info("Starting getTrafficProfileByCosClass6Allocations cos6"  );
    Query query = em.createNativeQuery(buildTrafficProfileByCosClassAllocationsQuery(direction, cosClassAllocation, routerType), TrafficProfile.class);
    query.setParameter(1, "cos6");
    query.setParameter(2, direction.name());
    query.setParameter(3, cosClassAllocation.getCos1());
    query.setParameter(4, cosClassAllocation.getCos2V());
    query.setParameter(5, cosClassAllocation.getCos2());
    query.setParameter(6, cosClassAllocation.getCos3());
    query.setParameter(7, cosClassAllocation.getCos4());
    query.setParameter(8, cosClassAllocation.getCos5());
    return  findSingleOrNoItem(query, "Traffic_Profile", "cos_model = cos6, direction = " + direction.name() + " cos1 = " + cosClassAllocation.getCos1() 
            + " cos2v = " + cosClassAllocation.getCos2V() + " cos2 = " + cosClassAllocation.getCos2() 
            + " cos3 = " + cosClassAllocation.getCos3() + " cos4 = " + cosClassAllocation.getCos4()  + " cos5 = " + cosClassAllocation.getCos5()  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `ClassOfService6Allocations` and supposedly `ClassOfService4Allocations` inherit from `ClassOfServiceAllocation` you can check, inside your for-loop, what is the type of the current object and then cast to this class, for instance:

```
for(ClassOfServiceAllocation alloc : cosClassAllocation) {

    if (alloc instanceof ClassOfService6Allocations) {
        ClassOfService6Allocations alloc6 = (ClassOfService6Allocations) alloc;
        //set your parameters using the alloc6 object
    } else if (alloc instanceof ClassOfService4Allocations) {
        ClassOfService4Allocations alloc4 = (ClassOfService4Allocations) alloc;
        //set your parameters using the alloc4 object
    }
```

Comment: ClassOfServiceAllocation only has `getClassName()` and `getAbsolutePercentage()`. We used to have a class that has `ClassOfService6Allocations` and `ClassOfService4Allocations` inherit from `ClassOfServiceAllocation` but not anymore.